# canvas.toDataURL blocked by Brave Shield cross site device-recognition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, cors, brave-browser

I am currently working on a webapp which will be used to upload files after a resize. When I am working on `localhost:3000`, the resize process works like a charm, but when I am working on `192.168.0.5:3000` for example (or another domain), **canvas.toDataURL returns an empty string instead of the base64** and the resize never ends.
This issue only occurs when the brave shields are enabled, and the reason behind the blocked element is a `cross site device-recognition`.

**What can I do for my canvas to be able to resize an image I am uploading to the browser and get it's dataURL and Blob, when I am not using localhost ?**

The idea is to get an file from an input, resize it to 16MP via a Canva, and get the blob of this canvas to send to the backend.
I have a `PictureCompress` function which will read the file with `new FileReader()` in order to get the `base64` of this file. After that I am creating a `new Image()` and set it's `src` to my reader `event.target.result` (the b64) and, `onload` I am supposed to create the Canvas to resize the image via `ctx.drawImage`, get the new base64 via `canvas.toDataURL` and then the blob.
This process is perfectly working on my webapp when running it locally, but when I change the url to access my machine IP (I expect it to be the same on a domain name), it is no longer working.
For example, there is a [live version of this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-kare-7ikwj) on `CodeBox` and the issue seems to occurs.

EDIT :

1. This issue only occurs when the url has a port (`192.168.0.5:3000` is not working, but `192.168.0.5` is working). Why ?
2. On firefox, the above fix does not work : `Blocked http://192.168.0.13/ from extracting canvas data because no user input was detected.`. Is it because it's not https ? To be continued ...

```js
function Uploader(props) {
  function PictureCompress(file, callback) {
    const fileName = file.name;
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onerror = error => console.warn(error);
    reader.onload = event => {
      const img = new Image();
      img.name = fileName;
      img.onerror = error => console.warn(error);
      img.onload = e => {
        const imageOriginalWidth = e.target.width;
        const imageOriginalHeight = e.target.height;

        const hvRatio = imageOriginalWidth / imageOriginalHeight;
        const vhRatio = imageOriginalHeight / imageOriginalWidth;

        const imageHvRatio = 16000000 * hvRatio;
        const imageVhRatio = 16000000 * vhRatio;

        const newWidth = Math.sqrt(imageHvRatio);
        const newHeight = Math.sqrt(imageVhRatio);

        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = newWidth;
        canvas.height = newHeight;

        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        const base64 = canvas.toDataURL(file.type);
        console.log(base64, newWidth, newHeight, file.type);
        canvas.toBlob(
          blob => {
            console.log(blob);
            callback(blob, base64);
          },
          file.type,
          0.85
        );
      };
      img.src = event.target.result;
    };
  }
  function recursiveUpload(index, files) {
    if (index >= files.length) {
      return;
    }

    const file = files[index];
    PictureCompress(file, resizedFile => {
      resizedFile.name = file.name;
      resizedFile.lastModified = file.lastModified;
      //MY API CALL, NOT THE ISSUE
    });
  }

  return (
      <input type={"file"} onChange={event => recursiveUpload(0, event.target.files)} />
  );
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I was having the exact same issue (on a very similar goal in my app ironically). The only exception being that the app works flawlessly in firefox, with a specified port. The issue is only present in Brave. As a temporary workaround, I've adjusted the browser settings to allow for functionality. It might be worth more tinkering with per site settings (whitelisting options maybe?). For example, I went into Brave settings->Shields->Device recognition, and select the option to 'Allow all device recognition attempts'. Then the app behavior is as expected.

Comment: @Rapid537 for the record, I don't have the brave issue when my domain name is set. With a PhysicalIP (192.xxx.x.x) the Brave Shields just block everything, but when I am using my dummy domain name, with SSL, I can use the canvas with no issues. Is it the same for you, or are you experiencing this issue with a setup domain name ?

Comment: (not with a setup domain yet, still working in production version dockerized front/back apps pre-deployment testing) You comment  //MY API CALL, NOT THE ISSUE, but have you tried specifying *HTTP://192.xxx.x.x* in your api call? (you probably have, but w/o seeing your actual api call in this post/sandbox, I just wanted to double check) Outside of that it could be related to CORS on your backend config (which we also cannot see here, so just a shot in the dark..) I'd like to compare what's working on my end and not working on yours, but w/o seeing more of the complete code it's hard to assume.